# In "Harry Potter", were the tales about Malodora Grymm and Leticia Somnolens the basis for Snow White and Sleeping Beauty respectively?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* video game, you can get two famous hag cards of Malodora Grymm and Leticia Somnlens and their tales are based on Snow White and Sleeping Beauty respectively.

The Leticia Somnolens page says:

> Her story appears to be the source of inspiration for the Muggle fairytale Sleeping Beauty.

And the Snow White page says,

> This Tale seems to be an actual account of the incident caused by Malodora Grymm in the Middle Ages.

Now, in the world of *Harry Potter*, if they ARE the basis for such tales, then their respective authors, Brothers Grimm and Charles Perrault, cannot reveal that for that would breach the Statute of Secrecy, so maybe they lie about where the get their stories from.

Is that right?

Comment: Um, I think you fail to understand a fundamental tenet of fairy tales: they **have** no author.

Comment: I meant the authors of the famous Snow White and Sleeping Beauty, Brothers Grimm and Charles Perrault respectively.

Comment: Neither of those are the authors of those tales. They simply collected them and published their versions of them, but the tales themselves are far older and are _folk tales_, so have no known author by definition. That said, can you clarify what you are asking? The quotes in your question seem to be answering you directly: yes, those were the basis for the stories, it says so right there. So what else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In the 2017 edition of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, the following appears in the Foreword:

> In 2001, a reprint of the first edition of my book *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* was made available to Muggle readers. The Ministry of Magic consented to this unprecedented release to raise money for Comic Relief, a well-respected Muggle charity. I was permitted to reissue the book only on condition that a disclaimer was included, assuring Muggle readers that it was a work of fiction. Professor Dumbledore agreed to provide a foreword that met the case, and we were both delighted that the book raised so much money for some of the world's most vulnerable people.

It would be reasonable, then, that other authors would have the same liberty.

Comment: So, would their respective authors be Squibs (non-magical people born to magic parents) who heard the tales from their parents and then decided to spread and disguise those true stories as fiction?